# Вставка пустой строки после выбранных регулярным выражением слов

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Требуется разделение текста от заголовков, путём вставки пустой строки после последних. Текст имеет следующую структуру:

> ```
> Заголовок заголовок заголовок
> Слово слово слово слово слово слово
> слово слово слово слово слово слово слово
> слово слово слово слово слово слово слово слово.
> ```

Приметы заголовка: начинается с большой буквы, не заканчивается знаком препинания, имеет длину до 30 символов, последующая строка тоже начинается с большой буквы.

Соответственно, нужно после строки с заголовком добавить второй возврат каретки. На данный момент в питоновом скрипте имеется следующее регулярное выражение, которое однако, находя заголовки, заменяет их пустой строкой:

```
текст = re.sub("^[А-Я]{1}.{,30}\n", "\n", текст)
```

---

**ДОБАВКА**

¡Спасибо пользователю [[@ReinRaus](/users/481/reinraus)](/users/481/reinraus) за данное предложенное решение:

```
текст = re.sub("^([А-Я]{1}.{,30}\n)", r"\1\n", текст)
```

Comment: видимо потому, что оно не прибавляет к найденному пустую строку, а просто заменяет его.

Comment: Именно. Вопрос в том, на что заменить "\n", что найденный текст оставался?

Пробовал варианты типа текст = re.sub("^[А-Я]{1}.{,30}\n", "[А-Я]\n", текст), но безуспешно.

Comment: Просто заменяйте не  

    \n
а  

    $0\n

Comment: Простите если неправильно понял, но имеется в виду так?
>текст = re.sub("^[А-Я]{1}.{,30}\n", "$0\n", текст)
Это заменяет найденный текст на $0.

Comment: Извините, в python нужно писать так:  

    "\\0\n"
это строка на которую заменять.

Comment: То есть:

текст = re.sub("^[А-Я]{1}.{,30}\n", "\\0\n", текст)

Это заменяет найденный текст на пробел :/

Comment: Тогда как-то так:  

http://ideone.com/Dod81I

Comment: ¿То есть так:

    текст = re.sub("^[А-Я]{1}.{,30}\n", r"\1\n", текст)

Это выдаёт ошибки при компилировании, включая
######sre_constants.error: invalid group reference

Comment: Смотрите внимательнее. Регулярное выражение изменилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

text= '''Заголовок заголовок заголовок
Слово слово слово слово слово слово слово
слово слово слово слово слово слово
слово слово слово слово слово слово
слово слово слово слово слово.'''

print ( re.sub("^([А-Я]{1}.{,30}\n)", r"\1\n", text) )
```

Результат:

```
Заголовок заголовок заголовок

Слово слово слово слово слово слово слово
слово слово слово слово слово слово
слово слово слово слово слово слово
слово слово слово слово слово.
```

Answer (score 0):

Может так:

```
p = re.compile("^[А-Я]{1}.{,60}\n", re.MULTILINE)
s1 = p.findall(f.read())[0]
p.sub(s1+'\n', s)
```

Вот так с английскими работает (если я правильно понял что требуется). С латиницей в юникоде осторожнее, там может количество символов *2 потребоваться.

Должно работать с \1 как [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519487/python-regex-re-sub-replacing-multiple-parts-of-pattern/3519536), но у меня не работает, поэтому я сохранил найденное и заменил.

Comment: Желательно использование re.sub. Также декларировать текст с самом скрипте нельзя, так как скрипт читает сторонние файлы.

Comment: поправил, у меня работает.

Comment: А как добавить этот код в существующий?


    текст = re.compile("^[А-Я]{1}.{,30}\n", re.MULTILINE)
    s1 = текст.findall(f.read())[0]
    текст.sub(s1+'\n', s)


выдаёт
    ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data

Comment: f.read() - то,что приходит с файла - текст. А переменную p оставьте на месте)

Comment: Простите, я не понимаю где это нужно класть, так как только учусь, да ещё и правлю чужой скрипт. Можно ли вопрос решить через re.sub, как выше пытается тов. ReinRaus?

Comment: так здесь ведь тоже через sub. Я не вижу скрипта, а телепатия - не мой конёк.

Comment: Нет, у вас же идёт через re.compile. Решение, предложенное пользователем ReinRaus выше, зато работает. Тем не менее, спасибо вам.